# Output Movie in Python cannnot by played

Tags: python, opencv

I want to convert a network camera video to grayscale and save it as an another video file.
I wrote the following code, but it does not work well.
However `detect.avi` is output, I can not play this file.
What is the problem?

```
rtsp_path = f"rtsp://{userid}:{pwd}@{ip_address}:{rtsp_port}/ipcam_h264.sdp"
video = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_path )
savepath = "detect.avi"
frame_Rate = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
height, width, dim = frame.shape
rec = cv2.VideoWriter(savepath, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), frame_Rate, (int(width), int(height)))

while (video.isOpened()):

   
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if frame is None:
        break

    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rec.write(img)

    if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        video.release()
        rec.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
rec.release()
```

I got the error message as below:

```
OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:267: error: (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

I got an error about CISCO OPENH264.
I put  openh264-1.8.0-win64.dll in python directory.
However , I got another errors as below.

```
    OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc.

[libopenh264 @ 000001b9e01c4700] [OpenH264] this = 0x000001B9DA5EC4D0, Error:MaxSpatialBitrate (288000000) should be larger than SpatialBitrate (536870911), considering it as error setting
[libopenh264 @ 000001b9e01c4700] [OpenH264] this = 0x000001B9DA5EC4D0, Error:WelsInitEncoderExt(), ParamValidationExt failed return 16.
[libopenh264 @ 000001b9e01c4700] [OpenH264] this = 0x000001B9DA5EC4D0, Error:CWelsH264SVCEncoder::Initialize(), WelsInitEncoderExt failed.
[libopenh264 @ 000001b9e01c4700] Initialize failed
[ERROR:0@15.734] global /build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (2985) open Could not open codec libopenh264, error: Unspecified error (-1313558101)
[ERROR:0@15.734] global /build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (3002) open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoWriter
[ERROR:0@24.573] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (597) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:267: error: (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

Comment: whatis the size of the file after saving?

Comment: Don't think this is linked to the issue but you call `video.release`, `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` and `rec.release` twice, you should erase it from the if sentence, and maybe call `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` after the release

Comment: Add False at `cv2.VideoWriter` after frame size. `rec = cv2.VideoWriter(savepath, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), frame_Rate, (int(width), int(height)), False)
`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do all of them, but still they do not work.
I use IP camera , so I need to press the button "q" to stop this program.
When I press the button, the program stops. But the recorded movie is not be saved.

Comment: It is possible that the DIVX encoder does not handle grayscale input.  Perhaps you should convert it back to RGB (it will still have all grey colors).